# How to use CAST,CONVERT and isNULL in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the query:

```
SELECT TOP 50 CONVERT(date, o.OrderDate)as OrderDate,ISNULL(rd.SerialNumbers,'') as SerialNumbers,CAST(o.SourceOrderID as varchar(50)) as SourceOrderNumber
From Orders o
```

Query is edited for question.

```
var lq= (
                    from o in db.Orders
 select new {,o.Name, o.Company, o.Address, o.Address2, o.City, o.State, o.Country, o.Email, o.Zip, o.Phone, o.ShipName, o.ShipCompany, o.ShipAddress, o.ShipAddress2, o.ShipCity, o.ShipCountry, o.ShipState, o.ShipPhone, o.ShipZip, o.OrderNumber, o.ShippingTotal }
            ).ToList();
```

I can make simple joins and select in LINQ but not getting idea how to get selects like one mentioned in query.

I am using EF

Comment: It would help if you told us what your schema is.

Comment: Don't try too much to translate SQL into LINQ. Instead: how would you use C# code to go from the values provided by the database (or EF) to the requested types? That might also work in LINQ.

Comment: Yes I am using EF. Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given there is no way to actually perform a `string` to `datetime` conversion as part of the DB query using LINQ, it's recommended you use `AsEnumerable` to switch the context of the list to run the actual conversion in memory

```
orders.Take(50)
      .AsEnumerable()
      .Select(x => new {
          OrderDate = x.OrderDate.Date,
          SerialNumbers = o.SerialNumbers ?? "",
          SourceOrderNumber = o.SourceOrderID.ToString()
      });
```

Comment: You might want to do a pre-`Select` to avoid pulling everything across from the database. (And yes, put the `Take` *before* the `AsEnumerable` too, otherwise you're pulling who-knows-how-many records...)

Comment: just wanted to note that if you're taking the top 50, OP, you'll want to do `orders.OrderBy().Take(50).AsEnumerable()...`

Comment: @Rawling point noted, however, it doesn't make much difference with regards to this being a useful answer (if anything, it would just complicate the example).

Comment: @DLeh why would `OrderBy` required? The OP doesn't appear to be ordering in any particular way.

Comment: Well usually if you're taking `TOP X` you want it in a particular order. I just put it there as an example of doing the order / take *before* the `AsEnumerable()`

Comment: I updated the question with my Linq I tried so far. I am using `ToList`

Comment: @James `Error 22 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @James this `DateTime.ParseExact(x.OrderDate, "yyyy-mm-dd" CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` still gives same error.

Comment: @James OrderDate is of type `DateTime`. Do I need to convert to String first?

Comment: @Volatil3 ah, I assumed `OrderDate` was a `string`, if it's a `Datetime` already then that's even easier. I presume it's just the `Date` value you are looking for?

Comment: @James yes only Date part is required this is why use `Date` in SQL

Comment: @James `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: @Volatil3 have you included the `AsEnumerable` call? Sounds like you haven't (or perhaps calling it *after* the `Select`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69238/discussion-between-volatil3-and-james).

Comment: I made it to work. `SourceOrderID` was nullable to converted to `int?`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

LINQ2SQL is actually bright enough to handle the parse in the code:

```
var q = from c in Customers
where c.PhoneNumber == "9075556658"
select new 
    { 
    SSN = c.SSN, 
    DOB = DateTime.Parse(c.BirthDate)
    };
q.Dump();
```

I just run that in LinqPad on my own database, and it worked fine.

NOTE: This was tested with Linq2SQL, not Entity Framework, which has a history of not be able to do things Linq2SQL has been doing for years.